# Pandas: append symbol to cells in column

Tags: python, pandas

I create dataframe with

```
df3 = np.round(df2[["All"]]/df['Gender'].count()*100, 2).rename(columns={"All":'%'})
```

and I want to add `%` after every number. How can I do it?
`df`:

```
Third party unique identifier   Qsex    Gender
9ea3e3cb6719f3d336d324c446f486bd    1    male
d1b69bc4cccf0afef66debf4e3f0643e    2    female
f574fc585db0cddef88306ef6f32da59    1    male
8bc0a586bf0abec653c29cf4160753f9    1    male
7c22b56929378ec2eb3a536b4f4bc4e0    2    female
23d8433168c46d57a271a6b979037094    1    male
5743b7eec1b018572b6c5b44542a67a5    2    female
f176289325aa4a6fa56c0179e9cbd101    1    male
c729933ff7db798ae07c59d971f40a70    1    male
```

df2

```
    Qsex      1.0    2.0     All
Gender                      
Female      0  72342   72342
Male    51537      0   51537
All     51537  72342  123879
```

Comment: Can you add sample df?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661968/add-a-percent-sign-to-a-dataframe-column-in-python

Comment: @jezrael add dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need first add `normalize` to [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html), then [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html), multiple by `100`, convert to `string` and last add `%`:

```
df2 = pd.crosstab(df.Gender, df.Qsex, margins=True, normalize=True)
        .round(2)
        .mul(100)
        .astype(str) + '%'

print (df2)
Qsex        1      2     All
Gender                      
female   0.0%  33.0%   33.0%
male    67.0%   0.0%   67.0%
All     67.0%  33.0%  100.0%
```

because if use `astype(str) + '%'` only:

```
df2 = pd.crosstab(df.Gender, df.Qsex, margins=True).astype(str) + '%'
print (df2)
Qsex     1   2 All
Gender            
female  0%  3%  3%
male    6%  0%  6%
All     6%  3%  9%
```