# How could I add the % to each value in the numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following numpy array:

```
arr= [[  0.          0.1046225518   0.          0.8953774482   0.        ]]
```

For the moment I have

```
values= str(np.around([arr*100],decimals=2))
```

returning:

```
 [[  0.          10.46   0.          89.53  0.        ]]
```

If I     `+ %` to values, it returns

```
 [[  0.          10.46   0.          89.53  0.        ]]%
```

The desired output is :

```
[[  0.          10.46%   0.          89.53%  0.        ]]
```

Comment: What should your output be? A numpy array of strings, or just a string?

Comment: numpy array of strings because after would like to turn to dataframe

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661968/add-a-percent-sign-to-a-dataframe-column-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned in a comment you'd like to convert this to a dataframe (I assume you mean a Pandas dataframe)...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Reproduce your numpy array
arr= np.array([[  0.0, 0.1046225518, 0.0, 0.8953774482, 0.0]])

# Convert to 1-Column DataFrame of % Strings 
# (use pd.Series() instead if you'd prefer this as a Pandas Series)
as_strings = pd.DataFrame(["{0:.2f}%".format(val * 100) for val in arr[0]])

# Assign column name
as_strings.columns = ['Numbers as Strings'] 

print(as_strings)

  Numbers as Strings
0              0.00%
1             10.46%
2              0.00%
3             89.54%
4              0.00%
```

thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23981926/1870832) for most of the key line of code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using pandas:

```
(pd.Series([  0.0, 0.1046225518, 0.0, 0.8953774482, 0.0]) * 10).round(2).astype(str) + " %"
```

Resulting in

```
0     0.0 %
1    1.05 %
2     0.0 %
3    8.95 %
4     0.0 %
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Also solution if need `0` only:

[`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) + [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html) + [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html) + [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html)

```
arr = np.array([[0.,0.1046225518,0., 0.8953774482, 0.]])

#DataFrame by constructor
df = pd.DataFrame(arr.reshape(-1, len(arr)), columns=['A'])

#convert 0 to string also for avoid mixed types - floats and strings 
df['B'] = df['A'].astype(str).where(df['A'] == 0, 
                                    df['A'].mul(100).round(2).astype(str).add('%'))
print (df)
          A       B
0  0.000000     0.0
1  0.104623  10.46%
2  0.000000     0.0
3  0.895377  89.54%
4  0.000000     0.0
```