# Pandas Dataframe: Removing numbers after (.) and adding % to it and renaming column in certain format

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

```
('Total Answered Calls', 'sum') ('Calls Received', 'mean')
329                                   99.83249581
197                                   98.02631579
162                                   99.24242424
57                                    100
73                                    97.82608696
```

> I want to in the given format with changed column names and values

```
Total Answered Calls          Calls Received
329                                   99%
197                                   98%
162                                   99%
57                                    100%
73                                    97%
```

Comment: For column titles: Are those columns titles? If so you can do df.columns = ['Total Answered Calls', 'Calls Received']. Please check this sounds similar for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084812/how-to-remove-decimal-points-in-pandas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a percent sign to a dataframe column in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661968/add-a-percent-sign-to-a-dataframe-column-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

If that's what you are looking for this may solve the problem:

```
data.columns = ['Total Answered Calls','Calls Received']
data['Calls Received'] = data['Calls Received'].astype(int).astype(str)+'%'
```